# How remove specific text from option

Tags: javascript

i need remove text "+ 0 Kč" from this options via Jquery, can you help me? Thx

```
 <option value="177" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Ginger +0 Kč</option>
 <option value="180" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Taupe +0 Kč</option>
 <option value="183" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Mocca +0 Kč</option>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use jQuery:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#choices option').forEach((option) => {
  option.textContent = option.textContent.replace(/ \+0 Kč$/, '');
})
```

```html
<select id="choices">
  <option value="177" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Ginger +0 Kč</option>
  <option value="180" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Taupe +0 Kč</option>
  <option value="183" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Mocca +0 Kč</option>
</select>
```

But if you want to:

```js
$('#choices option').each(function() {
  var $option = $(this);
  $option.text($option.text().replace(/ \+0 Kč$/, ''));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choices">
  <option value="177" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Ginger +0 Kč</option>
  <option value="180" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Taupe +0 Kč</option>
  <option value="183" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Mocca +0 Kč</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select option:contains("+0 Kč")').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.text($this.text().replace("+0 Kč"," "));    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="177" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Ginger +0 Kč</option>
 <option value="180" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Taupe +0 Kč</option>
 <option value="183" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Mocca +0 Kč</option>
  
</select>
```

Whit jQuery you can iterate the options text and edit whit

```
$this.text($this.text().replace("+0 Kč"," "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) in conjuction with [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) and JavaScript [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove every character after the first whitespace.

```js
$('option').each(function (index, element) {
    const newText = $(element).text().split(' ')[0];
    $(element).text(newText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="177" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Ginger +0 Kč</option>
    <option value="180" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Taupe +0 Kč</option>
    <option value="183" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Mocca +0 Kč</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, Iterate over options and use *slice* or *substring* to remove *text "+ 0 Kč"*.

```js
const options = document.querySelectorAll('option')
Array.from(options).forEach(option=>{
    option.innerHTML = option.innerText.slice(0, -5);//.substring(0, option.innerText.length - 5);
});
```

```html
<option value="177" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Ginger +0 Kč</option>
 <option value="180" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Taupe +0 Kč</option>
 <option value="183" data-surcharge-final-price="0" data-surcharge-additional-price="0">Mocca +0 Kč</option>
```